# Jelastic Eclipse Plugin - All Tomcat applications restart on Deploy

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jelastic

I have a Tomcat 7 server running on Jelastic.  I'm using the Jelastic Eclipse Plugin to Deploy my projects, and all is good.  However, I have more than one application deployed (in /webapps) on the Tomcat server and noticed that when I Deploy one project from Eclipse, the server restarts, thus restarting my unchanged application as well.

I had modified the server.xml to autoDeploy="false", but since it seems to be restarting the server, that wouldn't make any difference.

Is there some setting that would prevent this, or is it just the behavior of the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is а regular deployment procedure and there is no way to prevent it if you use Eclipse Plugin for deploying.

But you can deploy your project without the node restarting. There are two ways:

1. [Upload](https://docs.jelastic.com/application-configuration) yourproject.war into the **webapps** folder using Jelastic's DashBoard file manager:

[image]
[image]

2. Disable the restarting after projects deploying.
   Note: this option requires the administrative rights and you should contact your hoster to disable it.